# Short story about aliens that are parts of a spaceship

Tags: story-identification

I have a very vague recollection of a short story in which somehow the parts of a spaceship were aliens of different races, whose innate powers allowed them to perform a function (braking, steering...). The end revelation is about the nature of the ship's accelerator.

Any bell ringing?

Comment: @SQB how is this, a 3 year old question, a duplicate of a question asked 40 mins ago? :P

Comment: @Shevliaskovic Perhaps because SQB felt the newer Q was a better question than this one, in terms of detail. While [precedent for that exists](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate), I prefer this Q as it has had more exposure. Maybe someone can amalgamate the info?

Comment: @SQB - I agree and have used my super-duper-deduper-hammer on this question instead.

Comment: @user14111 This was flagged for re-opening under the [policy that story ID questions are not to be closed as duplicates unless both are accepted with the same answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7065/31936). When closing questions as duplicates, the better question/answer remains open and the other is marked as a duplicate, whether the better question is newer or older (i.e. the rule you mention has not been repealed).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That would be ["Specialist"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialist_%28short_story%29) by Robert Sheckley. Sheckley wrote dozens of brilliant and memorable short stories in the 1950s, and it's well worth tracking them down.

Comment: Sheckley was *awesome* indeed.

Comment: I read this recently -- great story.