# Short story, aliens and humans become part of a symbiotic space ship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m trying to find a short story I must have read in the 90’s in a collection.

Plot is;

A biological spaceship travels around the galaxy collecting creatures that are added to to itself as parts of its symbiotic collective. Each alien turns out to have a specific function in the ship, that becomes clear only when “abducted”.

Eventually a human is abducted and his purpose becomes clear.

I read many collections back then, stories from 60’s and 70’s possibly. I think the book had multiple authors. Would have been a second hand paperback or a library book.

I was living in the UK back then.

I’d love to read the story again, anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This sounds like "[Specialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialist_(short_story))", a short story by Robert Sheckley, first published in 1953.

As you say, there is a biological spaceship, composed of different intelligent creatures with particular specialities, such as Walls, Engine, Thinker, Talker, and so on. To travel faster than light they require a Pusher after theirs was injured and died during a photon storm. It turns out that humans are actually Pushers, even having the correct socket to interface with the ship. The Crew capture a human, and after an initial period of mistrust, he learns of the joy of collaborating with the Crew, and "pushes", so that the spacecraft speeds away.

The original story, published in *Galaxy*, is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1953-05/page/n69/mode/2up?view=theater). It has been collected in numerous anthologies, which you can check at [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45711).

Comment: Which would be duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118026/short-story-with-spaceship-and-humanity-not-realising-they-should-be-on-it.  The answer there has a link to the original *Galaxy* publication.

Comment: Thank you! That’s the one.